# template function overload in non-template class using SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, guideline-support-library

### TL;DR

A couple of templatized and overloaded non-templatized member functions in a non-templatized class should all end up routing through the same member function to perform the actual work. All the overloads and templatizations are done to convert the "data buffer" into `gsl::span<std::byte>` type (essentially a close relative to `std::array<std::byte, N>` from the [Guidelines Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL))

---

### Wall of code

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include <gsl.h>
#pragma warning(pop)

// convert PoD into "memory buffer" for physical I/O
// ignore endianness and padding/alignments for this example
template<class T> gsl::span<std::byte> byte_span(T& _x) {
    return { reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(&_x), sizeof(T) };
}

// implementation of physical I/O (not a functor, but tempting)
struct A {
    enum class E1 : uint8_t { v1 = 10, v2, v3, v4 };
    bool f(uint8_t _i1, gsl::span<std::byte> _buf = {});    // a - "in the end" they all call here
    bool f(E1 _i1, gsl::span<std::byte> _buf = {});         // b
    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral<T>::value > >
        bool f(uint8_t _i1, T& _val);                       // c
    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral<T>::value > >
        bool f(E1 _i1, T& _val);                            // d
};

bool A::f(uint8_t _i1, gsl::span<std::byte> _buf)
{
    std::cout << "f() uint8_t{" << (int)_i1 << "} with " << _buf.size() << " elements\n";
    return true;
}

bool A::f(E1 _i1, gsl::span<std::byte> _buf)
{
    std::cout << "f() E1{" << (int)_i1 << "} with " << _buf.size() << " elements\n\t";
    return f((uint8_t)_i1, _buf);
}

template<class T, typename>
bool A::f(uint8_t _i1, T& _val)
{
    std::cout << "template uint8_t\n\t";
    return f(_i1, byte_span(_val));
}

template<class T, typename>
bool A::f(E1 _i1, T& _val)
{
    std::cout << "template E1\n\t";
    return f(_i1, byte_span(_val));
}

int main(){
    A a = {};
    std::array<std::byte, 1> buf;
    long i = 2;

    // regular function overloads
    a.f(1, buf);           // should call (a)
    a.f(A::E1::v1, buf);   // should call (b)

    // template overloads
    a.f(2, i);             // should call (c)
    a.f(A::E1::v2, i);     // should call (d)

    struct S { short i; };
    // issue
    //S s;
    //a.f(3, s);             // should call (c)
    //a.f(A::E1::v3, s);     // should call (d)

    //// bonus - should use non-template overrides
    //S sv[2] = {};
    //a.f(5, sv);            // should call (a)
    //a.f(A::E1::v1, sv);    // should call (b)
}
```

### Details

The `struct S` is a PoD and it is tempting to change the template's `enable_if` to use the `std::is_trivial` or `std::is_standard_layout`. Unfortunately both these solutions "grab too much" and end up matching `std::array` (even if they **do** fix the compilation error of the `//issue` block).

The solution I have right now looks like a dead-end as my gut feeling is to start adding more template parameters and it seems to be getting very hairy very soon :(

### Question

My goal is to achieve the following: use the `class A`'s `bool f()` member function without too much syntactic overhead for any PoD (possibly including C arrays - see "bonus" in code) as shown in the body of `main()` and no runtime function call overhead for types that are auto-convertible to `gsl::span` (like `std::array` and `std::vector`).

### Ideally...

I'd like to have a single templatized function per first parameter (either `E1` or `uint8_t`) with multiple specializations listed outside the class's body to further reduce the perceived code clutter in the class's declaration and I can't figure out the way to properly do that. Something like the following (illegal C++ code below!):

```
struct A {
// ...
template<typename T> bool f(uint8_t _i1, T& _val);
template<typename T> bool f(E1 _i1, T& _val);
};

template<> bool f<is_PoD<T> && not_like_gsl_span<T>>(uint8_t /*...*/}
template<> bool f<is_PoD<T> && not_like_gsl_span<T>>(E1 /*...*/}
template<> bool f<is_like_gsl_span<T>>(uint8_t /*...*/}
template<> bool f<is_like_gsl_span<T>>(E1 /*...*/}
```

If this is not achievable I'd like to know why.

I'm on MSVC 2017 with C++17 enabled.

Comment: Are you sure that it is supposed to call (a) in `a.f(1, buf)` and `a.f(A::E1::v1, buf)` cases? More like it is supposed to call (c), but wont because it is ignored by `enable_if` condition.

Comment: The Standard specifies that "plain overload" functions are chosen over templates if a proper match is found

Comment: That is true, but in those cases you pass `std::array` while the methods declared with `gsl::span`. So obviously the types are different. If you passed `gsl::span`, then it would be clear. Why do you expect it to call (a) and (b)?

Comment: My question is "how to make it call a) and not b)". Well, that is part of the question, anyway

Answer (score 1):

The first answer was a little wrong, for some reasons, I was totally confused by gsl. I thought it is something super specific. I am not using Guideline Support Library, though I have seen it and it looks good.
Fixed the code to properly work with `gsl::span` type.

```
struct A {
  enum class E1 : uint8_t { v1 = 10, v2, v3, v4 };

private:
  template <typename T>
  static auto make_span(T& _x) ->
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T&, gsl::span<std::byte>>::value,
                            gsl::span<std::byte>>::type {
    std::cout << "conversion" << std::endl;
    return _x;
  }

  template <typename T>
  static auto make_span(T& _x) ->
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<T&, gsl::span<std::byte>>::value,
                            gsl::span<std::byte>>::type {
    std::cout << "cast" << std::endl;
    return {reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(&_x), sizeof(T)};
  }

public:
  template <typename T, typename U>
  bool f(T _i, U& _buf) {
    static_assert(
      std::is_convertible<U&, gsl::span<std::byte>>::value || std::is_trivial<U>::value,
      "The object must be either convertible to gsl::span<std::byte> or be of a trivial type");

    const auto i = static_cast<uint8_t>(_i);
    const auto span = make_span(_buf);
    std::cout << "f() uint8_t{" << (int)i << "} with " << span.size() << " elements\n";
    return true;
  }
};
```

Comment: This is "close enough". Not exactly a solution (so not marking it as such) but definitely an improvement on what I have.

Comment: You also can check if type `T` in `f` is `E1` or `uint8_t` within `static_assert`.